# EntityFramework.SqlServer and EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer are missing

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dnx

I am trying to use Entity Framework with SQL Server. There are plenty of examples that are saying that I need to add `EntityFramework.SqlServer` package in order to get it working. However as I understood [they renamed the package to EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/85). In my case I cannot find any of these packages. The only package that has `EntityFramework` and `SqlServer` names in it I found is `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact`, but then I am getting following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
>   FileName=EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   FusionLog=""   HResult=-2146234300
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>          at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)
>          at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.TryGetInstance(String
>   providerTypeName)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterSqlServerProvider()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type
>   type, String name)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`2
>   t)
>          at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver
>   r)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver
>   resolver)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection
>   internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)  ...   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146234300
>          Message=A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
>          InnerException:

**project.json**

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-Iwatch.Accounting.Web.Angular-03e60bec-48ff-4682-8638-aa06e0f97867",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer": "3.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Iwatch.Accounting.Data.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
        "Iwatch.Accounting.Data.Logic": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you use `NuGet` to add `EntityFramework` to your solution/project? Usually, adding EF using NuGet will install all dependencies, including `EntityFramework.SqlServer` and `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`.

Comment: yes I did. Actually I've just created fresh new MVC project with Identity authentication and it added all the main packages

Comment: Assuming, that there is `project.json`, the question should be re-tagged to appropriate versions of ASP .NET and EF.

Comment: Package does exist on nugget. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServer/7.0.0-beta5
Please remove reference to EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact that is version 6.1.3 and it would require EF.SqlServer 6.1.3 but the version of EF is different in your project json hence the exception.

Comment: First, you seem to be on ancient version of dnx/aspnet - there were 4 releases since beta5 and even if there was a bug in that release a lot has changed and the bug might have been fixed and since it is a beta release I doubt anyone will look at the issue unless it is reproducable on the latest bits. So move to rc1. 
You seem to be mixing EF6 and EF7 /EF Core1. These versions are not compatible - you can't use EF7/EF Core 1 with EF6 providers. It just does not work.